# Uniform "density" of bezier segments

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, bezier-curves

I have a bezier line which has been given a width (fill:full). I would like to give it a rope texture. For that I activated "Use UV for mapping" in the Curve-Tab and used the node setup which can be seen in the screenshots. This basically works but the UV coordinates seem to be different in all segments. You can see this at the changing density of normals which are diplayed in edit mode. This results in the material looking different for each segment. Is there a way to get a uniform distribution over the whole bezier curve?

I know I could just use meshes instead of bezier curves, but I am doing the rigging of a three-masted history sailing vessel wich will feature (many) hundreds of ropes in the rigging, some with sagging etc., so for now I would like to stay with the curves.
[image: Change in material appearance at new segment]
[image: Changing normal density at new segment]

Thanks in advace and best regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 6):

When one handle is longer than the other, you will get a speed discontinuity at that control vertex (the curve's derivative will be discontinuous in that point). That's how Bezier splines work. There's no way around it other than using different spline type.

The way to solve this is to use a tile-able rope mesh piece, like this:

[image]

Put an *Array modifier* on it to tile it to the curve length and a *Curve modifier* to fit it to the curve:

[image]

And you are done, even when the curve has discontinuity, the mesh does not. Don't forget to provide enough subdivisions on the curve (64) and on the mesh:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In fact, this IS possible to get uniform distribution so lets roll...

1. Activate LoopTools in preferences
2. Convert Your spline into a mesh using the Alt+C shortcut
3. In EDIT mode select all the verticies and use the previously activated LoopTools - its SPACE function distributes all the points evenly
4. Convert Your mesh into a spline again using the Alt+C shortcut
5. DONE!

   Hope it helps mate ;).

   JayM

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem for splines. The automatic UV mapping depends on the spacing of your control points.

Either you find a way to normalise the b-spline with python (like [this](http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/normalize-spline) for 3dsmax) or you create a new spline with only two points initially. First point at 0, 0, 0, second point at 1, 0, 0. Then subdivide the spline. The more subdivisions, the smoother the result. The make the new spline follow your other spline. Don't forget to activate UV mapping. And you'll have smooth and regular mapping.