# Blender uniform Bezier curve without using its shape

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

Ok, I Don't know how to properly express what I'm looking for, but I'll try:

I have a BEZIER curve like this:

[image]

My problem is that in edit mode, the distance from the resolution points isn't constant:

[image]

I need to use this curve to animate a follow-path constraint, and the non uniform points lenght results in an unsmooth animation. I already looked at this question: [Uniform "density" of bezier segments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45342/uniform-density-of-bezier-segments)

But it was asked and answered more than 1.5 years ago. Is there anyway in the new versions of blender to do it? It's alright to create new verts too but the important thing is that the curve doesn't lose its shape. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Convert curve to mesh.
2. Loop Tools -> Space (edges).
3. Convert mesh to curve.

[image]

Comment: sorry, but where is the loop tools -> Space?

Comment: @marcus loop tools is an addon that needs to be enabled.