# How to make curve have evenly distributed segments?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I ask as the curve simplify addon doesn't work well. The result should be Like maya REBULID a curve. I want to do it in Blender but can't. [image]

how to rebuild a curve have same distance segment?

Comment: could you please precise what you mean by "have average segment"? What does Maya do exactly?

Comment: I understand it as averaging the position of the control points along the curve. On the picture the geometry density is higher on the left, and the question is about having a homogenous density

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45342/uniform-density-of-bezier-segments   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-evenly-space-vertices-along-several-segments-bezier-curve

Comment: Geometry Nodes: `Resample Curve`

Answer (score -2):

Subdivide your cylinder like 7 or more times and apply the Curve modifier. The more subdivisions, the more rounded the shape.